# Behaviour of cv2.imwrite with np.float64 data

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Looking at the [cv2 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html), I got the impression that one should be able in Python to match the writing out of `np.float64` data by a `np.clip` followed by type coercion to `np.uint8`. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Reproducible example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=300, size=(64,48,3))
arr2 = np.clip(arr, 0, 255)
arr3 = arr2.astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite('out1.png', arr)
cv2.imwrite('out2.png', arr2)
cv2.imwrite('out3.png', arr3)

arr1a = cv2.imread('out1.png')
arr2a = cv2.imread('out2.png')
arr3a = cv2.imread('out3.png')
print((arr1a==arr2a).all())
print((arr1a==arr3a).all())
```

yields `True` for the first check and `False` for the second check.

This indicates that (1) `cv2.imwrite` indeed calls `np.clip(arr, 0, 255)` on the array before writing it out; (2) it doesn't then call `.astype(np.uint8)` (or at least, that's not all).

My goal is to understand what exactly `cv2.imwrite` is doing to `arr`. In other words, how can I calculate an array identical to `arr1a` in my example above, without saving an intermediate file?

Comment: Did you look at the images in `arr1a` and so on? How do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `arr2` and `arr3` is that `arr3` has had the fractional component of each value truncated. The difference between `arr2a` and `arr3a` is sometimes 0, and sometimes 1. It looks like `imwrite()` might round the values before converting to integers, rather than just removing the fractional part as `astype()` does.

Let's do some experimenting to see if this is true.

```py
cv2.imwrite('out2b.png', arr2-0.5)
```

produces a PNG file that is identical to `out3.png`. Likewise,

```py
arr3 = np.round(arr2).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('out3b.png', arr3)
```

produces a PNG file that is identical to `out2.png`. Thus, it seems that indeed `imwrite()` will round the input floating-point values.

Comment: This seems to work. I had assumed that the astype conversion was itself rounding but clearly not - I suppose it probably rounds down or up rather than like np.round(). Confusing behaviour but thanks for elucidating

Comment: @MobeusZoom Casting a floating-point value to a integer discards the fractional part. 5.9 becomes 5. This is common among most programming languages because it's how the hardware does it. Very few languages put in the extra computation to round instead. This is not only the NumPy `astype()` behavior, plain Python does the same: `int(5.9)=5`. It's the same in C, C++, Fortran, Java, ... MATLAB is the only language I've encountered that implicitly rounds before casting.